# Form field data value clear

Tags: wordpress, forms, form-submit, elementor, jet-engine

I make a form by Crocoblock jetengine form. Now I want to when user submit the form then the form data value will be clear. My form ID=5503. If anyone help me then please give me the exact solution and how can I do it please clarify.

I want to submit the form and after submitting the data value will be clear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JetForm already has this feature in-built. Take a look at your form settings and you should be able to toggle the 'Clear data on success submit' on so that the form clears once the user submits the form successfully. See screenshot below

[image]